# Get the Left element of a Either function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a function in Haskell
`getCorError :: a -> b -> Either c [Error]`,
being `Error = Expected c` 
On another function, which returns `-> [Error]`, I want to return `[Expected (getCorError a b)]` if `getCorError` returns Left or [Error] otherwise.
I get a type error when doing `[Expected (getCorError a b)]`. I have tried many things, like writing Left before the parentesis and after, and many others, and I haven't been able of doing this.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It is much more effective to post the code than to attempt to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

if I get your question right then what you are looking for is the [`either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:either) function.

You should be able to use it like this:

```
either (return . Expected) id $ getCorError a b
```

of course in a context where `a` and `b` are defined - it's impossible to give you more than this hint because your question is really lacking details here.

The way this works is like this:

if `getCorError a b`

- returns `Left c` then `return (Expected c)` is used and `return` here is just `\a -> [a]` (it's in the list monad)
- returns `Right errs` then `id errs` is used